# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'db2cli64.lib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, lib

OS : Windows 10 
Python Version ( 32-bit ) : Python 3.8.1

```
Package    Version
---------- --------
pip        20.0.2
setuptools 41.2.0
```

I am trying to install ibm-db package using `pip install ibm-db`.

It initially resulted in "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."

After resolving the above by installing Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019.

I am now getting the error -

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'db2cli64.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Comment: `db2cli64.lib` is most probably a part of DB2 itself or DB2 SDK.

Comment: I downloaded the odbc/cli fix pack from ibm_db, registered the dlls, including that one, no go.  I believe about a month ago I saw ibm saying idb_db is not going to work with 3.7+.  I wound up installing 3.6 and "pip install ibm_db" succeeded without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

got the same error with python 3.8 32 bit. May be 64 bit should be used . 
for my issue I uninstalled and used the 3.7.6 64 bit . and it works fine.

Comment: To let others understand your solution better, it will be better to provide your environment information such as OS version, python version, package version and the detailed steps in bullet format.